# Add a symbol to a .docx file

Tags: c#, docx

I want to be able to add a "tick" to the end of a sentence using the [DocX library](http://docx.codeplex.com).

```
//Create the table
Table signingTable = document.AddTable(18, 6);
//....many lines of code
string mySentence = "Hello World" + <tick>;
signingTable.Rows[entryItem + 1].Cells[3].Paragraphs.First().Append(mySentence);
```

such that when my table renders it will have a tick symbol next to the text `Hello World`. Can someone help with the encoding I need to add to make this work?

Comment: U+2713? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tick mark is ascii character 252 in the wingdings font.

You need to add another run to the paragraph, set the run font to wingdings and add chr(252) into it.

Using the DocX library you would do something like the following:

```
char tick = (char) 252;

p.Append("Hello World").Append(tick).Font(new FontFamily("Wingdings"));
```

Comment: Sorry I have updated it now, I was mixing my languages! :)

Comment: I had to do tick.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Using SDK OpenXML you would do something like this:

```
p.Append(new Run( new SymbolChar() { Font = "Wingdings", Char = "F0FE" }));
```

Comment: I would suggest this could be a comment instead of an answer, because it does not meet the "using the DocX library" requirement.